# How can I track "checkedChange" events for multiple Switch elements in a list?

Tags: nativescript

In a NativeScript Core app, I have a dynamically rendered list of users, and foreach user there are two Switch elements; one for involvement and one for assignment.

Firstly, how can I bind an "checkedChange" event to all the Switch elements in that list at once, after the list has been loaded or reloaded (and not to any other Switch elements on that page)?

Secondly, the assignment switch should only be enabled if the involvement switch is checked, or disabled and unchecked elsehow. How can this be achieved in a good way?

Thirdly, the event triggers a function that is suppose to save the change. How should I retrieve info about type (involve or assign) and user id?

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4woZ.png)

**To clarify:**

I know about the method of giving the switch element an ID and bind it statically, like:

```
 const mySwitch = page.getViewById("mySwitch");
 mySwitch.on("checkedChange", (args) => {
   // Do something
 });
```

and

```
<Switch id="mySwitch" .../>
```

But in this case, I'm loading a list of users from an API, using a ViewModel and ObservableArray. Each record contains two Switch elements, and giving them unique ID's and binding each one seems like a bad solution.

If it was a web app, I would have added extra attributes to the Switch element, like:

```
<Switch data-type="user-involvement" data-uid="10" .../>
```

and the collectively bind changes to all elements where data-type is "user-involvement".

Is there any way to do something similar in {N} Core?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using {N} Core flavour then you should be able to add
  `checkedChange` listener upon `loaded` event of `Switch`.
- Within the `checkedChange` event of `Switch` you could update the `checked` property of other `Switch` by updating the Observable attribute it's in bound with.

Comment: Binding of static Switch elements is not the challenge, it's binding checkedChange to a list of dynamic elements (where id binding doesn't seem to be a good solution to me)...please see the extra clarification I've added to my original question.

Comment: As I mentioned already in my answer, use the loaded event of Switch itself instead of Page, so you can do something like `args.object.on('checkedChange', listener);`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=uVkHIJ&v=3). On Initial load, in youe XML, you can have 2 switches and can control the second switch based on first switch's state.

```
  <Switch checked="{{involved}}" loaded="switchLoaded" />
  <Switch checked="{{assigned}}" isEnabled="{{involved}}" />
```

while in your js file.

```
countries: [
      { name: "User 1", involved: true, assigned: false },
      { name: "User 2", involved: true, assigned: false },
      { name: "User 3", involved: false, assigned: false },
      { name: "User 4", involved: true, assigned: false },
      { name: "User 5", involved: true, assigned: false },
    ],
```

Also you can bind listeners on loaded method.

```
function switchLoaded(args) {
  console.log(args.object.bindingContext);
  args.object.on("checkedChange", (args) => {
    console.log("checkedChange ", args.object.checked);
  });
}
```

In **args.object.bindingContext** , you have the access of data that you can control.

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried it yet, but that looks like exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Great, I have added a link for playground sample as well, that you can use. You can upvote the answer so that people with similar issue can get the benefit.

Comment: By the way, any idea how to change the view model observable when the switch is changed? I.e. if an involved switch turnes to false, assigned for that user should changed to false as well...

I've tried something like this

`homeViewModel.forEach(function(e,i){
 if (args.object.bindingContext.name==e.name) {
  homeViewModel.set("homeViewModel["+i+"]['assigned']",true);
 }
});`

...but no change...